# Swift making sksprite node move faster with time

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

I have a sprite node that spawns in via a function:

```
    let NBrick1 = SKSpriteNode(texture: Brick1)
    NBrick1.setScale(0.04)
    NBrick1.position = CGPointMake(0.0, CGFloat(y1 + bounds/2))
    NBrick1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: NBrick1.size)
    NBrick1.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    BrickPairs.addChild(NBrick1)
```

I am using this SKAction to move the bricks:

```
   let moveBricks = SKAction.moveByX(-distanceToMove, y: 0.0, duration: NSTimeInterval(0.01 * distanceToMove))
   let removeBricks = SKAction.removeFromParent()
   BricksMoveAndRemove = SKAction.sequence([moveBricks,removeBricks])
```

I was wondering if there was a way to make the brick move faster as time goes on.

Comment: you can access/change the duration with MoveBricks.duration. So in your case you'd make the duration smaller that way your sprite will be reaching the same distance in a shorter time span.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "move faster as time goes on." Do you want the sprites to move faster the next time you create them or do you want existing ones to speed up?

Comment: I would like next time i create them to be moving faster

Comment: @DanielMihaila is correct. You should make `0.01` a variable and decrease it over time.

Comment: right now I'm running a function and an skrunblock:
let timeChange = SKAction.runBlock({self.timeChanger()})
which runs:
func timeChanger(){
        timechanger = timechanger - 0.00001
    }
But I'm not really seeing an effect in the speed of the bricks timechanger is the variable for .01

Comment: Since `0.00001` is small relative to `0.01`, I wouldn't expect to see much of a difference in speed per iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its actually quite simply and you do not need to get involved with `SKActions`. The code will below will speed up the movement of a sprite, or multiple sprites, (if you apply the same code.) What it is doing is changing the position of the sprite every frame by a little bit more each time. This is the `moveFactor` variable. To change the start speed and rate that it speeds up, change the value that I put in.

```
var moveFactor:CGFloat = 0.5

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    sprite.position = CGPoint(x: sprite.position.x + moveFactor, y: sprite.position.y)
    moveFactor *= 1.005
}
```